# Reactjs checkbox cannot be checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have this code in Reactjs that display a label with a checkbox

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';


class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super(...arguments);
  }

  checkboxClicked(e) {
      this.props.test.clicked = e.target.checked;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <li>
            <label>

                <input type="checkbox" value={this.props.test.id} checked={this.props.test.clicked} onChange={this.checkboxClicked.bind(this)} />
                {this.props.test.text}

            </label>
        </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

The checkbox and text is well displayed, but when I click on it, it refused to get checked. The value of `this.props.test.clicked` is changed but not the ui in the browser.

Can somebody tell me that I am missing?

Comment: Can you provide a live example reproducing the problem?

Comment: Here is a live example https://jsfiddle.net/2kctv533/

Comment: The component is never rerendered because the state never changes. Use state, not props.

Comment: @AndrewL.It might not be the right way to do so, but in the parent components, I use the props value to find which checkbox was checked... In your method, how can I know which Test was checked?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to change props.
Try to use `state` instead.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';


class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super(...arguments);

      this.state = { checked: this.props.test.clicked };
  }

  checkboxClicked(e) {
      this.setState({checked : e.target.checked});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <li>
            <label>

                <input type="checkbox" value={this.props.test.id} checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.checkboxClicked.bind(this)} />
                {this.props.test.text}

            </label>
        </li>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: It might not be the right way to do so, but in the parent components, I use the props value to find which checkbox was checked... In your method, how can I know which Test was checked?

Comment: Can you show me your parents components who need to test if those checkbox are checked ?